# display php search results in html table

Tags: php

im running this php script and not quite getting the result i want. at the moment its giving me this output

> scuba tank
>
> mike
>
> 0.00
>   450.00
>   5.00
>
> 2012-06-04 18:50:22
>
> scuba tank
>
> liam
>
> 80.00
>   350.00
>   2.50
>
> 2012-06-04 19:00:09
>
> Displaying 3 results
>
> scuba tank
>
> josh
>
> 410.00
>   0.00
>   5.00
>
> 2012-06-04 19:00:09

its pretty much what i want except the line displaying 3 results should be displayed at the end instead of before the last entry. what do i need to do to my script to fix this?

```
<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = null;

    // ========================================
    $dbhost = @mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Unable to connect to server");

    @mysql_select_db("divebay") or die("Unable to select database");

    $var = "scuba";
    $query = trim($var);

    if(!isset($query)){
        echo "Your search was invalid";
        exit;
    } //line 18

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM auction WHERE name LIKE '%" . $query . "%'";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    mysql_close($dbhost);

    if($numrows == 0){
        echo "Sorry, your search did not return any results";
    }

    $i = 0;

    while($i < $numrows){
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        $ID = $row['ID'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $owner = $row['owner'];
        $holder = $row['holder'];
        $start = $row['sprice'];
        $current = $row['cprice'];
        $instant = $row['iprice'];
        $inc = $row['incprice'];
        $image = $row['img'];
        $time = $row['stime'];
        $length = $row['duration'];

        echo "
            <?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'utf-8'?>
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
            <html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
            <head>
                <title>searchdbresults</title>
            </head>

            <body>  
                <table style='width = 800px;'>
                    <tr style ='height = 200px;'>
                        <td style ='width = 200px;'></td>

                        <td style ='width = 300px;'>
                            <div style ='180px'> $name </div>
                            <div> $owner </div>
                        </td>

                        <td style='width =200px'>
                            <div style='height = 100px'> $current </div>
                            <div style='height = 50px'> $instant </div>
                            <div> $inc </div>
                        </td>

                        <td> $time </td>
                    </tr>
        ";

        $i++;   
    }

    echo "
                <tr> Displaying $numrows results</tr>
            </table>
        </body>
        </html>
    ";
?>
```

Comment: when you use inline css styling, you must use double quotes ! <div style="color:#000;"></div>

Comment: The obvious is that he is using = instead of : inside the style attribute.

Comment: @LiamWarnes Seriously, i think you should go and follow some tutorials to get the basics of html/css/php, the code is containing several (basic & big) errors ...

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment, but there is several problems in your code.

1st the style must double quote

```
<div style="width:100%;">
```

for example.

2nd : there must be a td inside a tr for this line :  Displaying $numrows results

and last one i see is : you have this :

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>

<head>
<title>searchdbresults</title>
</head>
<body>
```

inside your while loop, so its several times in your page, and it must not

You also have the table opening in your while loop, but not the closing. So it's opened several times, but opened only once.

edit : you also need to add protection into your sql query

Answer (score 1):

Your script is generating "messy" HTML. From what I see your so generated HTML page will have (in the current example) 3 DOCTYPE definitions, 3 `head`'s as well as 3 opening `table` tags and only one closing `/table`.  And also you don't need to `echo` every single html entity, you can use plain html in php files
Try something like that:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>

<head>
<title>searchdbresults</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = null;

// ========================================
$dbhost = @mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Unable to connect to server");

@mysql_select_db("divebay") or die("Unable to select database");

$var = "scuba";
$query = trim($var);

if(!isset($query)){
    echo "Your search was invalid";
    exit;
} //line 18

$sql = "SELECT * FROM auction WHERE name LIKE '%" . $query . "%'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
mysql_close($dbhost);

if($numrows == 0){
    echo "Sorry, your search did not return any results";
}
else{
?>
<table style='width = 800px;'>
<?php 
    $i = 0;

    while($i < $numrows){
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $ID = $row['ID'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $owner = $row['owner'];
    $holder = $row['holder'];
    $start = $row['sprice'];
    $current = $row['cprice'];
    $instant = $row['iprice'];
    $inc = $row['incprice'];
    $image = $row['img'];
    $time = $row['stime'];
    $length = $row['duration'];
?>
<tr style ="height: 200px;">
<td style ="width: 200px;"></td>
<td style ="width: 300px;">
    <div style ="width: 180px"><?php echo $name; ?></div>
    <div><?php echo $owner; ?></div>
</td>
<td style="width: 200px;">
    <div style="height: 100px;"><?php echo $current; ?></div>
    <div style="height: 50px;"><?php echo $instant; ?></div>
    <div><?php echo $inc; ?></div>
</td>
<td><?php echo $time; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
      i++;
    } //end of while
} //end of else
?>
<tr>
    <td colspan="4">Displaying <?php echo $numrows; ?> results</td>
</tr>
</table>
</html>
```

And also consider preventing SQL Injection too: http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be much better off if you separated your php and html into separate files.  You seem to be losing track of your opening " and closing ".  If you want your

```
<tr> Displaying $numrows results</tr>
```

at the bottom of your page, then take it out of the table.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest simplifying your table a little bit, maybe taking the 'Displaying $numrows results' out of the table entirely.

The line '<tr> Displaying $numrows results</tr>' is not valid HTML. <tr> means 'Define a new table row', but it needs a <td> inside it to wrap the content. Because most rows of your table contain several TD elements, whilst this row only contains one piece of information, you would need to tell that table cell to [span multiple columns](http://www.ironspider.ca/tables/tablecells2.htm).

A good way of debugging this sort of thing is to feed the generated HTML to http://validator.w3.org/,  or replace the $variables with sample data and feed the template code to a validator. This is usually a little frustrating at first (as it will force you to be exact about the HTML version you want to use, etc) but it is a good way of tracing problems.  If you feed the following HTML snippet into the W3 validator, it will give you some useful feedback:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head><title>A</title></head>
<body>

<table><tr><td>aaa</td><td>bbb</td></tr>
<tr><td>cccc</td><td>dddd</td></tr>
<tr>Test</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The validator tells you that: Line 7, Column 5: character data is not allowed here

```
<tr>Test</tr>
```

In other words, the TR element should not directly contain text.

It also says that: Line 7, Column 13: end tag for "tr" which is not finished

```
<tr>Test</tr>
```

"Most likely, you nested tags and closed them in the wrong order... Another possibility is that you used an element which requires a child element that you did not include. Hence the parent element is "not finished", not complete. For instance, in HTML the <head> element must contain a <title> child element, lists require appropriate list items (<ul> and <ol> require <li> ...), and so on."

Once you have the static HTML looking, and validating, the way you want, you can then add the PHP loops back in, but this time you can compare the script output to your working HTML example.